# Android Things Update/Deploy APK at remotely Installed Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, iot, android-things

I was exploring and working with Android Things and I made a small project of LED Blinking, Referring to these [steps](http://myandroidthings.com/post/tutorial-7) I came across the functionality of rolling out the image update by OTA in Channels like Stable/Canary/Beta, which will include the APK too, it seems the whole OS will get updated by this way containing the app in it.

Here are my queries depending on the certain situations:

1. Suppose my PI is installed at the remote location and in order to update the APK is there any way to do that with OTA?
2. If not then what would be the effective way to update the PI with updated APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to update the apps, you can create an OTA update including your new APK and release it in one of the channels that you've setup.

Comment: Thanks, I will check through the docs for setting up the channel, as I tried for the releasing the update through OTA but did not get it on PI.

Comment: It won't be instant necessarily. You may also want to take a look at the [UpdateManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/update/UpdateManager) to do custom update behavior.

Comment: Yes, this would be a thing to look on, thank you for sharing this.